# Angular2 animations [@triggerName] not working in *ngFor

Tags: angular, angular2-animation

Basically I want to be able to apply my animation to a specific box when a condition is fulfilled. In my app this need to happen when the user give an answer for question1 (in Component1) -> through a shared service -> in COmponent2 I get notified about it, and if the answer is correct I will scale the box with id=1(I used id just to point the importance of the specificity of the box)

The `[@triggerName] = "my_value_from_expression"` value not working added by `*ngFor` but the value exists;

If I do this: `ng.probe($0)._debugInfo._view.changeDetectorRef._view` on the box, gives me this (_expr_3 is the looked value):

> ...
>
> _el_0:div#1.box
>
> _expr_2:"1"
>
> _expr_3:"animate1"
>
> _expr_4:"Box1"
>
> ...

So I have this:

**frame.component.ts**

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-frame',
templateUrl: './frame.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./frame.component.css'],
animations:[ 
  trigger('boxScale',[
    state('true', style({
        transform: 'scale(1.2)',
      })),
    state('false', style({
    transform: 'scale(1)',
  })), 
  transition('false => true', animate('100ms ease-in')),
    transition('true => false', animate('100ms ease-out')),
  ]),]
})
export class FrameComponent implements OnInit {
  answ:string[];
  boxes: string[] = [];
  animate1:boolean = true;
  animate2:boolean = false;

constructor(private _commService: CommunicateService) { 
  this._commService.answerSource.subscribe((result:string[]) => {
    this.answ = result;
    this.animate(result)
})

  for(let i = 1; i <= 2; i++ ){
    this.boxes.push("animate"+i);
  }
}
animate(result){
 /***** result: ['q_id',corect_answ','user_answ'] *****/
  if(result[1] != undefined && result[1] === result[2]){
      this.animate1 = !this.animate1;
      this.animate2 = !this.animate2;
    }
  }
}
```

**frame.component.html**

```
<div class="boxes">
   <div class="box" [@boxScale]="animate1">Box_1</div>
   <div class="box" [@boxScale]="animate2">Box_2</div>
   <div *ngFor="let box of boxes; let i = index; " class="box" id="{{i+1}}" [@boxScale]="box">Box{{i+1}}</div>
</div>
```

What I try to do is to add with ngfor the correct value for `[@boxScale]` so the result should be:

```
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box" [@boxScale]="animate1">Box_1</div>
  <div class="box" [@boxScale]="animate2">Box_2</div>
  <div class="box" id="1" [@boxScale]="animate1">Box1</div>
  <div class="box" id="2" [@boxScale]="animate2">Box2</div>
</div>
```

First two hardcoded elements works just fine with those `animate1` and `animate2` variables but the other two, generated with `*ngFor` are not working at all.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: boxes: string[] = [];  you need boolean array i think

Comment: look in the constructor - my boxes array looks like this: ["animate1","animate2"]

Comment: I use Augury and the array is ok

Comment: there is an issue between `[@boxScale]` and `="box"` when `*ngFor` runs

Comment: [@boxScale] require true or false not strings.

Comment: yep - but `animate1` is `true` in the begining then toggle between `true/false`

Comment: the first two hardcoded divs work just fine; only those generated by ngfor don't

Comment: yes because of this   animate1:boolean = true;  animate2:boolean = false; in *ngFor it won't be based on above values it will be based on string array called boxes.

Comment: and the interpolation not working like this, right? - I kind of come to this tought too

Comment: ok, my main reason for doing this is because I try to target a specific element and animate just that one

Comment: how can I do this to actually work?

Comment: can you create a plunker? showing the issue  i will correct that for you.

Comment: if you use 1 or 0 alternative to true and false it might work.

Comment: got to go in 10 min....no difference with 0 and 1

Answer (score 0):

**Try something like this**  Check the [Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/6c05lF80QgCDZryYzUKp/) if code below doesn't make sense.

```
import { 
    Component, OnChanges, Input, 
    trigger, state, animate, transition, style 
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector : 'ease-inout',
  animations: [
    trigger('boxScale',[
    state('true', style({
        transform: 'scale(1.2)',
      })),
    state('false', style({
    transform: 'scale(1)',
  })), 
  transition('false => true', animate('100ms ease-in')),
    transition('true => false', animate('100ms ease-out')),
  ])
  ],
  template: `

    <div class="boxes">
      <div class="box" [@boxScale]="animate1">Box_1</div>
      <div class="box" [@boxScale]="animate2">Box_2</div>
    <div *ngFor="let box of boxes; let i = index; " class="box" id="{{i+1}}" [@boxScale]="box">Box{{i+1}}</div>
</div>
  `
})
export class EaseInOutComponent implements OnChanges {
  boxes: boolean[] = [];
  animate1:boolean = true;
  animate2:boolean = false;

  constructor()
  {
    // just for example
    this.boxes.push(this.animate1);
    this.boxes.push(this.animate2);
    console.log(this.boxes) //[true, false]
  }

}
```

Hope this will help..

[image: Output]

Comment: please look to my answer below - your answer is good, but only for non changeable values; if I modify animate1 value first hardcoded box works but first generated don't(because it's boxScale value is true not variable `animate1)

Answer (score 0):

@MMK - please check the [update](https://plnkr.co/edit/ePiaNfvrmVgwej45iZ5y?p=preview)

```
 <div>
    <button (click)="box1()">Toggle Box1</button>
    <button (click)="box2()">Toggle Box2</button>
</div>    
box1(){
  this.animate1 = !this.animate1;
}
box2(){
  this.animate2 = !this.animate2;
}
```

Comment: @MMK - basically I want to be able to apply my animation to a specific box when a condition is fulfilled. In my app this need to happen when the user give an answer for `question1` (in `Component1`) -> through a shared service -> in `COmponent2` I get notified about it, and if the answer is correct I will scale the box with `id=1`(I used id just to point the importance of the specificity of the box)

Comment: so I've tried  to accomplish this by giving unique `[@boxScale]` variables like: for box 1=> `[@boxScale] ="animate1" `  for box2  `[@boxScale] ="animate2" `

Comment: Then  with your help I've discovered that in my array I push a string not a class object, and for that with *ngFor, box represent a string not an object of class like I initially thought - on the other hand if I push `this.animate1` in `*ngFor` box will be `true or false`(this.animate1 value) not `animate1` itself like I need to

Comment: The only way I could achieve this in the way I've started is by hardcode 20 div elements with specific `animate_n` value but I don't want to do that

Comment: I'm opened to other suggestions as well

Comment: Aha, I see - you modify the array value directly - No matter how I try to do this I cannot get away of using multiple variables, I guess would be easier not to use `ngFor` and just write raw html

Comment: how about using single toggle variable? set default value to true and then in a function you toggle it... ?

Comment: I need 20 different variables, one on every box - because I need at one moment in time to be able to animate a single box(know by something: id/animate value/function)